# General script to replace a word

Tags: bash, perl, unix, sed

I am aware of several such way like sed,perl which can replace words from text files.

I was trying to create an alias say "rep word1 word1 filename" (when typed from unix terminal does the same)

where rep will be alias which internally will use the sed utility to replace words. "word1" is to be replaced by "word2" in "filename".

Please help me in coming up with such utility.

Also word1 and word2 should take care of special characters. Main intention is that users can perform such operations without being worried about usage of sed/perl one liner.

Comment: You can't do this with an alias, because they can't substitute parameters. You need to use a script or shell function.

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. SO is not a free code-writing service, we help you fix up your code.

Comment: Would something like "sed 's/word1/word2/g' filename" work?

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your motivation: i am able to do this now. I am passing $1 an $2 shell variable into sed "s/$1/$2/g"  . This utility i have aliased as rep and now <rep x y filename >  is working . Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

A perl one-liner like the following could work just fine:

```
alias rep="perl -i -pe 'BEGIN {(\$s,\$r) = splice @ARGV, 0, 2} s/\Q\$s/\$r/g'"
```

And invoke it using

```
rep foo bar file.txt
```

#### Explanation:

**Switches**:

- `-i[extension]`: Edit `<>` files in place (makes backup if extension supplied)
- `-p`: Creates a `while(<>){...; print}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line.

**Code**:

- `BEGIN {($s,$r) = splice @ARGV, 0, 2}`: Pull first two arguments into variables for search and replace.
- `s/\Q$s/$r/g`: Replace all references of `$s` with `$r`